# Get sibling tag content within two tag interval : ]tag1; tag5[ = tag2, tag3, tag4 with Xpath -Python -Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I want to get the content of sibling tags in a sibling interval.
Ex from this [website](https://www.flashscore.com/team/bayern-munich/nVp0wiqd/results/) :

```
<div class="event__header top event__header--no-my-games event__header--noExpand"><div class="icon--flag event__title fl_6" title="Europe"><div class="event__titleBox"><span class="event__title--type">EUROPE</span><span class="event__title--name" title="Champions League - Play Offs">Champions League - Play Offs</span></div><span class="toggleMyLeague active 1_6_xGrwqq16" title="Remove this league from My Leagues!"></span></div><a href="#" class="event__info active">Draw</a></div>

<div id="g_1_K0LZPMeo" title="Click for match detail!" class="event__match event__match--static event__match--oneLine"><div class="event__time">23.08. 21:00</div><div class="event__participant event__participant--home">Paris SG</div><div class="event__scores fontBold"><span>0</span>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<span>1</span></div><div class="event__participant event__participant--away fontBold">Bayern Munich<svg class="winner___259228F icon--winner"><title></title><use xlink:href="/res/_fs/build/symbols.f1bc6b2.svg#winner"></use></svg></div><div class="event__part">(0&nbsp;-&nbsp;0)</div><svg class="info___3Lh1dXC icon--info"><title></title><use xlink:href="/res/_fs/build/symbols.f1bc6b2.svg#info"></use></svg><span class="wld wld--w">W</span></div>


<div id="g_1_0Q5Y9xYO" title="Click for match detail!" class="event__match event__match--static event__match--oneLine"><div class="event__time">19.08. 21:00</div><div class="event__participant event__participant--home">Lyon</div><div class="event__scores fontBold"><span>0</span>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<span>3</span></div><div class="event__participant event__participant--away fontBold">Bayern Munich<svg class="winner___259228F icon--winner"><title></title><use xlink:href="/res/_fs/build/symbols.f1bc6b2.svg#winner"></use></svg></div><div class="event__part">(0&nbsp;-&nbsp;2)</div><svg class="info___3Lh1dXC icon--info"><title></title><use xlink:href="/res/_fs/build/symbols.f1bc6b2.svg#info"></use></svg><span class="wld wld--w">W</span></div>

<div class="event__header event__header--no-my-games event__header--noExpand"><div class="icon--flag event__title fl_8" title="World"><div class="event__titleBox"><span class="event__title--type">WORLD</span><span class="event__title--name" title="Club Friendly">Club Friendly</span></div><span class="toggleMyLeague 1_8_Ox0MZaDH" title="Add this league to My Leagues!"></span></div><a href="#" class="event__info active"></a></div>
```

How access tags `<span class='wld'>` in all tags `<div class='event__match>`that localed between the tags `<div class='event__header'>` ?
Limit the scope of results between 2 tags.

Me, I want access all tags `<span class='wld'>` in all tags `<div class='event__match>`that localed between the tags `<div class='event__header'>` contained a tag `<span>` contained sub string 'Champions League' and the tags `<div class='event__header'>` not contain of tag `<span>` container the of sub string 'Champions League'of all the page.
In other words access to all results of match champions league.

I did this :

```
competition = 'Champions League'
results = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'" + competition + "')]//ancestor::div[@class='event__header']//following-sibling::div/span[class='wld']")))
```

and this return logically a error 'TimeoutException'

**Edit :**

This don't return me exception thanks to the answer of @KunduK, I also want add than the process must be repeated that means than if there is of tags with even conditions somewhere in page of website so I must also get this elements and those as many times as necessary.

My question is:

For limit the range of results obtained at a known variable, for example 3, we normally let's use this `position()<=3`if I'm not mistaken.
Me, I search a thing like this for example : `position()<=div[@class='event__header]/span[contain(text(), =! Champions League])` whose the `position()` is of course equal to `[@class='event__header]/span[contain(text(),Champions League])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally found solution.
Here is my code :

```
def type_competition(typeMatch, rankingLeague, rankingCup, noTypeMatch, driver):
     a = '4'
     results = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'event__header')]/div")))
     listCompetMatch = []
     listNotCompetMatch = []

     i = 0
     for elem in results:
         i += 1
         elem = str(elem.text)
         ranking = elem.find(rankingLeague)
         rank2 = elem.find(rankingCup)
         rank3 = elem.find(noTypeMatch)
         compet = elem.find(typeMatch)
         if compet != -1:
             listCompetMatch.append(i)
         elif ranking != -1 and compet == -1:
             listNotCompetMatch.append(i)
         elif rank2 != -1 and compet == -1:
             listNotCompetMatch.append(i)
         elif rank3 != -1 and compet == -1:
             listNotCompetMatch.append(i)

     b = 0
     resultsFinal = []
     for elemresult in listCompetMatch :
         while listNotCompetMatch[b] < elemresult:
             b += 1
             if listNotCompetMatch[-1] < elemresult and listNotCompetMatch[-1] == listNotCompetMatch[b-1]:
                 listNotCompetMatch.append(listed[-1] +1)
                 break
         for positionElem in range(elemresult+1, listNotCompetMatch[b+1]):
             positionElem = str(positionElem)
             resultsFinal.extend(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
             "//div[contains(@class,'sportName')]/div[position() ='" + positionElem +"']/span[contains(@class,'wld')]")))) 

     return resultsFinal

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
type_competition('Champions League', 'Standings', 'Draw', ' Friendly', driver)
```

Explication :
I accessed to node that contain all results, that is to say the tags that contains the matchs results and the competitions then with first `for` loop, I identified the position of each tag that contain the competitions name. the second `for` loop is used to get the results in the interval, between a position (number) of `listCometMatch` and of `listNotCompetMatch`.

We can write it as an equation like this :
`resultsFinal` =  ] `listCometMatch` ; `listNotCompetMatch` [

Answer (score 1):

Use either of the `xpath`.

```
competition = 'Champions League'
results = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'" + competition + "')]//ancestor::div[contains(@class,'event__header')]/following-sibling::div//span[contains(@class,'wld')]")))
```

OR

```
competition = 'Champions League'
results = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'event__header')][.//span[contains(text(),'" + competition + "')]]//following-sibling::div//span[contains(@class,'wld')]")))
```

---

**Update:**

```
competition = 'Champions League'
baselist = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'event__header')][.//span[contains(text(),'" + competition + "')]]/following-sibling::div")))

for item in range(len(baselist)):
    try:
       print(baselist[item].find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'wld')]").text)
       print(baselist[item].find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'event__participant--home')]").text)
    except:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I get good the results match after the tag `<div class='event__header' <span Champions League </span></div>`but I also receive all results of the page after this while I want only to receive the results of tags localed between this tag above and tag  `<div class='event__header' <span Bundesliga </span></div>` for example

Comment: @thestar : Sorry not clear what you after? If you post a new question and mentioned your expected output you are after from webpage that will help other contributor to help you. Thanks.

Comment: @thestar : The best way to fetch records you can do that `for result in results[:3]:
    print(result.text)` This will retrieve first 3 records from list.

Comment: But how do I manage to stop at a tag and not at a pre-defined number. because I can't know how many results there are between the first tag and the second. If it's possible

Comment: @thestar : There is another way you can do that.Use try..except block.Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I finally found a solution (see my answer)